# Принудительное удаление директории c#

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть папка, в ней запущены n процессов, существует ли встроенный метод принудительного удаления папки ? который автоматически закроет все процессы ? или же мне придется делать вручную по такому принципу :

1. Получить все файлы в папке
2. Найти все запущенные файлы
3. "Убить" найденные процессы
4. Удалить папку

Comment: Если файлы были запущены через потоки NTFS, то можно. В противном случае, на мой взгляд, только так, как вы описали.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov не подскажите, как это сделать ? буду благодарен примеру, спасибо

Comment: вот про запуск файлов через потоки NTFS: https://geektimes.ru/post/77818/  Но такой подход имеет ограниченное применение